# How to pair with bluetooth device in android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Hello Everyone I am working on Bluetooth and I want to pair my device with the finded bluetooth and connect with the paired bluetooth.

I want to know how to do this. And I have also read about client server approach in which we use bluetoothserver socket and bluetooth socket and listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord and createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord methods in which we pass mac and uuid.

I want to know where we use this approach and how to find the remote device UUId. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the mentioned methods, at least for **pairing** the devices.

Try using Intents to pair. This code might let you get more familiar with Bluetooth.

```
    public void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device)
{
    String ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST = "android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST";
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    String EXTRA_DEVICE = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
    String EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT = "android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT";
    int PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN = 0;
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE, device);
int PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN = 272;
intent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN);
sendBroadcast(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PAIR_DEVICE);
```

If you want a better approach on how to connect these paired devices, take a look at Bluetooth on AndroidDevelopers:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

> Link resources:
>
> http://pastebin.com/N8dR4Aa1
>
> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient

Comment: thanks Machado but after pairing how to connect with that device and where we use these two method i.e client server approach?

Comment: There are some useful documentation and also, source code examples at Google Developers webpage. Please check the edited answer.

Comment: I have read out their but not able to found why they are used so can u please tell.

Comment: RFCOMM BluetoothSocket is a method to start a secure outgoing connection to a remote device using SDP lookup of UUID.
It is designed to be used with listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(String, UUID) for peer-peer Bluetooth applications.

The remote device will be authenticated and communication on this socket will be encrypted.

You should use this socket only if an authenticated socket link is possible. Authentication refers to the authentication of the link key to prevent man-in-the-middle type of attacks.

Comment: PAIRING_REQUEST needs BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED so most app just can't do that.